# Vendor libs in ASP.NET MVC file structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, file-structure

I'm the client-side guy at my job and for the web application we're building I am introducing some new JS libs besides the already residing jQuery and jQuery UI. We use the standard folder structure setup with CSS and images in `~/Content` and JS in `~/Scripts`. In the latter we have our internally developed libs categorized into subfolders such as `~/Scripts/Plugins`.

However, now I want to add i.e. TinyMCE and find myself confused. NuGet installs all TinyMCE-related files to `~/Scripts/tinymce`, but `tinymce/skins` holds CSS and images which I feel should not be contained in the `~/Scripts` folder.

What is the **proper** way to structure vendor libs within the MVC file structure? Or, if there is no proper way, is there a proposed best practice? I don't feel like ******* up the original neat structure too much. Note that I am not looking for creating bundles, that lies in the future and the on-disk structure is a separate concern.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the larger gripes I've heard recently. There is no global standard on what should go where. It also really doesn't help [when there is no official TinyMCE package](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=tinymce) so one person can do it one way, and another person can do it another way.

Comment: As a very standards-compliant type of person this makes me worried. If we look at other JS libs dependant on stylesheets and images such as jQuery UI or Twitter Bootstrap -- how do these integrate into the .NET MVC structure?